# kotlin coroutines, why the async {} returned deferred returns different value when calling await() after a Log statement is added

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

in the kotlin coroutines [doc's sample](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/composing-suspending-functions.md)

it has a sample (modified a little to get log in android app for testing it)

```
fun main_test2() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    //sampleStart
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        println("+++ The answer is ${concurrentSum()}")
    }
    println("+++ Completed in $time ms")
    //sampleEnd
}

suspend fun concurrentSum(): Int = coroutineScope {
    val one = async {
        Log.w("+++", "+++ enter async one{} bf doSomethingUsefulOne()") . //<== cause one.await() returns different value
        doSomethingUsefulOne()
        Log.w("+++", "+++ enter async one{} after doSomethingUsefulOne()")
    }
    val two = async {
        doSomethingUsefulTwo()
    }
    //one.await() + two.await()

    one.await().also {println("+++ one.await(): $it")} + two.await().also {println("+++ two.await(): $it")}
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulOne(): Int {
    delay(1000L) // pretend we are doing something useful here
    return 13
        .also {
            Log.e("+++", "+++ doSomethingUsefulOne() return $it")
        }
}

suspend fun doSomethingUsefulTwo(): Int {
    delay(1000L) // pretend we are doing something useful here, too
    return 29
        .also {
            Log.e("+++", "+++ doSomethingUsefulTwo() return $it")
        }
}
```

I added some log to show the execution flow in the `suspend fun concurrentSum()`,

```
val one = async {
        Log.w("+++", "+++ enter async one{} bf doSomethingUsefulOne()") . //<=== added log
        doSomethingUsefulOne()
        Log.w("+++", "+++ enter async one{} after doSomethingUsefulOne()") . //<=== added log
    }
```

but the result then becomes 85 (because the one.await() now returns 56 not 13) instead of 42,

why the log causes the different result?

the log for without that two Log.w()s

```
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines E/+++: +++ doSomethingUsefulOne() return 13
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines E/+++: +++ doSomethingUsefulTwo() return 29
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines I/System.out: +++ one.await(): 13
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines I/System.out: +++ two.await(): 29
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines I/System.out: +++ The answer is 42
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines I/System.out: +++ Completed in 1009 ms
```

and the log with that two Log.w()s:

```
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines W/+++: +++ enter async one{} bf doSomethingUsefulOne()
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines E/+++: +++ doSomethingUsefulOne() return 13
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines W/+++: +++ enter async one{} after doSomethingUsefulOne()
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines E/+++: +++ doSomethingUsefulTwo() return 29
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines I/System.out: +++ one.await(): 56
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines I/System.out: +++ two.await(): 29
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines I/System.out: +++ The answer is 85
com.example.android.kotlincoroutines I/System.out: +++ Completed in 1006 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad the

```
val one = async {
        Log.w("+++", "+++ enter async one{} bf doSomethingUsefulOne()")
        doSomethingUsefulOne().also {
            Log.w("+++", "+++ enter async one{} after doSomethingUsefulOne()")
        }
    }
```

code block returns the Int is from the last statement, which was the Log.w() that returns its own int.

should be using .also{} on the `doSomethingUsefulOne()` to keep the original return.

don know how to close this question.